# Which subsets of the integers arise as the set of exponents of power endomorphisms for some group?

Tags: group-theory, group-homomorphism

A group $G$ is said to be an $n$-abelian group if the $n$th power map is an endomorphism of $G$.

Given a subset $S$ of the integers, three necessary conditions for $S$ to be the set of all integers $n$ for which $G$ is an $n$-abelian group for some fixed group $G$ are the following:

1. $1 \in S$
2. If $m,n \in S$, then also $mn \in S$.
3. If $n \in S$, then also $1-n \in S$ (together with the first condition, this implies that $0 \in S$).

> **Question**: Conversely, is the conjunction of the above three conditions also sufficient for $S$ to be the set of all integers $n$ for which $G$ is an $n$-abelian group for some fixed group $G$?

The idea, of course, is to let $G$ be the quotient of the free group $\langle x,y\rangle$ on two generators by the normal subgroup generated by all elements of the form $(xy)^n y^{-n} x^{-n}$ where $n \in S$.

The problem here is that conceivably, $G$ could be an $n$-abelian group for some $n \notin S$. The question then asks whether this problem will ever happen.

Comment: Use `$\langle X\rangle$` for $\langle X\rangle$.

Comment: By the way, the structure of $n$-abelian groups was determined by Alperin; but the set of integers you ask about is also associated to other groups: the $n$-Bell and the $n$-Levi groups (groups in which $[x^n,y]=[x,y^n]$ and group in which $[x^n,y]=[x,y]^n$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A group $G$ is $n$-abelian if $(ab)^n = a^nb^n$ for all $n$.

The set you are looking at is

$$\mathcal{E}(G) = \{ n\in\mathbb{Z}\mid (ab)^n = a^nb^n\}.$$

That set forms a **Levi system**. This was studied by L.C. Kappe:

- Kappe , L.C. *[On n-Levi groups](https://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01191994).* Arch. Math. (Basel) 47 (1986), no. 3, 198–210. [MR0861866](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=861866) (88a:20048)

Your conditions are not quite enough. A set of integers is a Levi system if and only if it satisfies the following 5 conditions:

1. $n,m\in W$ implies $nm\in W$.
2. $n\in W$ implies $1-n\in W$.
3. $0\in W$.
4. There exists $w\in W$, $w\gt 0$, such that for all $n\in W$, $n^2\equiv n\pmod{w}$ and every integer congruent to $n$ modulo $w$ is in $W$.
5. If the congruence classes of both $n$ and $n+1$ modulo $w$ lie in $W$, then $n\equiv 0\pmod{w}$.

Kappe proves that a set of integers is equal to $\mathcal{E}(G)$ for some $G$ if and only if it is a Levi system or it equals $\{0,1\}$.

See [this mathoverflow answer](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/284226/groups-for-which-the-n-power-map-is-a-homomorphism/284266#284266) for this and related concepts and references.